# How to pass variable from views to model in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Voiceapi(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    voice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="voice_data")
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets
import requests
import gdown
from pydub import AudioSegment
import speech_recognition as sr
from .serializers import *
from .models import *
import  time
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from urllib.request import urlopen

# create a viewset
class VoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # define queryset
    queryset = Voiceapi.objects.all()

    # specify serializer to be used
    serializer_class = VoiceSerializer
#
    print(Voiceapi.objects.values())

    datas = Voiceapi.objects.values()
    print(datas)
    for i in datas:
        try:
            print("Audio File-->",i['name'])
            audio_url = i['name']
            audio_id = i['id']

            def VoiceRecognizer(audio,audio_id):
                r = sr.Recognizer()
                with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
                    audio_text = r.listen(source)
                    try:
                        text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
                        print(text)
                   
                        Voiceapi.objects.filter(pk=audio_id).update(voice_text=text)
                    except:
                        print('Audio Not Clear')
            audio = "/home/venpep/voicetotext/messages/media/test.wav"
            VoiceRecognizer(audio,audio_id)
        except:
            print("Not audio file")
```

I need to pass the variable "text" from my view.py to models.py to set the default in voice_text.Is there any solution to get the text from the view page. The text variable is a basic string that needs to pass to the models.py

Comment: Currently, it is already what you do with your **Voiceapi.objects.filter(pk=audio_id).update(voice_text=text)**. I think you do not explain correctly your problem. If you are error, please add it and explain what happend for now ?

Comment: This will update the existing json file. Instead the default should be text. When I post the data in postman It should return text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understood from your comment, you can override the **[save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/)** in `django model` and put your logic, in this way you can edit field value before save it and send it in response

```
class Voiceapi(models.Model):
      ...
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```